# Keyboard appearing briefly when popping viewcontroller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

I'm experimenting an issue with the numeric pad when popping the current UIViewController from the UINavigationController.

In my current UIViewController. I have a few UITextField and a "Save" button in the UINavigationBar. The expected behavior is as follows:

When the user taps "Save", the keyboard must hide and a network operation is performed. In its callback, an UIAlertView is shown. When user dismisses this UIAlertView, a notification raises and the current UIViewController performs

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The thing is, if "Save" is pressed with the keyboard still showing, after performing the popViewControllerAnimated, the keyboard appears briefly and from left to right (as if it was visible in the previous UIViewController).

I've tried

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder]
```

when user taps "Save", when user dismisses the UIAlertView, and even in the

```
viewWillDisappear
```

method. Some other answers suggest using

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

but it doesn't work either.

If I could use the regular keyboard it would be trivial to override

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

to hide it when user taps "Return", "Done", etc. But being the numeric pad doesn't allow you to show that "finish" button.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you all for your time

Comment: you need to add done/cancel button to your numeric pad.

Comment: Use [self.view endEditing:YES];  before   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @T_77 I've tried     [myTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone]; and it doesn't work

Comment: @Dev I tried that too, and doesn't work either

Comment: Try my answer. I just posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Set the text field delegate and its return type as Done and pad as numeric pad.

```
  _textField.delegate = self;
_textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
[_textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

and now add the buttons to keyboard:

```
    -(void)addButtonsToKeyboard
{
    UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];


    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil)
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(kbDoneAction:)];

    UIBarButtonItem* seperatorItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];


    UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(kbCancelAction:)];


    [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton,seperatorItem, doneButton, nil]];
    _textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
}
```

and to hide the keyboard:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

and your Done action method is:

```
    -(void)kbDoneAction:(id)sender
{
    [_textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and Cancel action method is:

```
    -(void)kbCancelAction:(id)sender
{
[_textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to call addButtons method on viewDidload

Comment: Still not working. As a workaround, I'd disabled the save button until kDoneAction is called, but it misses the point of hiding it when hitting "Save"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. I ended up delaying the `popViewControllerAnimated` a little longer than the keyboard animation duration (`0.333` seconds).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using the below code. It works fine for iOS 8 and below version

    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
            UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:B_title
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {
                                           [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

                                       }];
        [alertVC addAction:cancelAction];
        [self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
}
```